# sh script not running with Crontab, but runs manually

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

Hi I have to jobs scheduled in crontab. I didn't create any dependency between those jobs. both sh scripts work manually but only the first sh works with cron tab.

46 08 * * * /Users/joaopimenta/Documents/joaopython/scripts/runScript.sh
48 08 * * * /Users/joaopimenta/Documents/joaopython/scripts/automatecsv.sh

Not the second one -> sh script for the second:

```html
cd /Users/joaopimenta/Documents/joaopython
source env/bin/activate

python ./ProdSqlToCsvHeaders.py
```

I wonder if it's because the second sh, is actually pulling a python script which generates a csv file always with the same name but with new data everyday. So the script just keeps replacing a csv file with the same name but new data.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the best way is to execute script directly

```
/yourenv/bin/python yourscript.py
```